# A question about a surjective ring homomorphism polynomial ring with real coefficients to complex number

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{R}[x]$ be the polynomial ring with real coefficients. Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and define a ring homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{C}$ by the following formula:
$$
\phi:f(x) \to f(a+bi)
$$
(a) Determine the condition of $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $\phi$ is a surjective.

(b) Suppose that $\phi$ is surjective, find a generator of the ideal Ker$(\phi)$.

I was totally lost in the first question. So does it suffice to show that for any complex number, there exists a real coefficients polynomial that it values at the complex. Can I just let $a = x$ and $b \neq 0$? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of $a+ib$ is a polynomial of minimal degree $P$ such that $P(a+ib)=0$, if $f(a+ib)=0$, we can write $f=UP+V$ where $\deg(V)<\deg(P)$ (Euclidean division). We deduce that $f(a+ib)=U(a+ib)P(a+ib)+V(a+ib)=V(a+ib)=0$, since $P$ is minimal, $V=0$.

The map $e(f)=f(a+ib)$ factors by $\bar e:\mathbb{R}[X]/(P)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

Suppose that $b=0$, write $P=X-a$ it is the minimal polynomial of $a+ib$ and $e$ is not surjective since $\mathbb{R}[X]/(X-a)\simeq\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose $b\neq 0$

The minimal polynomial of $a+ib$ is $(X-a)^2+b^2$ and the kernel of $f$ is $(P)$, and $f$ is surjective since $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathbb{R}[X]/(P(X))=2=\dim_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{C}$.